# Joi: Require exactly two of three fields to be non-empty

Tags: joi

Here is a simple version of my schema.

```
var schema = Joi.object().keys({
    a: Joi.string(),
    b: Joi.string(),
    c: Joi.string()
});
```

I want a, b, c to be exactly 2 out of 3 non-empty. I.e.:

- if a, b are not empty, c should not be set
- idem with circular permutation of a,b,c
- of course, if 2 or more are empty, throw an error too

Tried using `.or()` but obviously doesn't do the trick. Looked into `.alternatives()` but didn't get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's tricky to find an elegant way to handle this without stumbling into circular dependency issues. I've managed to get something working using [`.alternatives()`](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v13.1.0/API.md#alternatives---inherits-from-any) and [`.try()`](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v13.1.0/API.md#alternativestryschemas).

The solution in its raw form would be this:

```
Joi.alternatives().try(
    Joi.object().keys({
        a: Joi.string().required(),
        b: Joi.string().required(),
        c: Joi.string().required().valid('')
    }),
    Joi.object().keys({
        a: Joi.string().required().valid(''),
        b: Joi.string().required(),
        c: Joi.string().required()
    }),
    Joi.object().keys({
        a: Joi.string().required(),
        b: Joi.string().required().valid(''),
        c: Joi.string().required()
    })
);
```

It's certainly not pretty and could get pretty bloated if any more dependencies are introduced.

In an attempt to reduce the amount of repetition, the following would also work:

```
var base = {
    a: Joi.string().required(),
    b: Joi.string().required(),
    c: Joi.string().required()
};

Joi.alternatives().try(
    Joi.object().keys(Object.assign({}, base,
    {
        a: base.a.valid('')
    })),
    Joi.object().keys(Object.assign({}, base,
    {
        b: base.b.valid('')
    })),
    Joi.object().keys(Object.assign({}, base,
    {
        c: base.c.valid('')
    }))
);
```